# How to hook on key presses

Tags: c#, winforms, hook, keypress

Control.KeyPress is not usable for me.
I have an WinForms app with many controls included one into another and KeyPress never occurs when it should in my opinion.
I want to set some global hook for my window. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried binding keypress to the form?

Comment: I don't know what is binding. I simply tried this. MainWnd.KeyPress += some_handler; Then set breakpoint in that handler and it never stops there when I pressing the keys. MainWnd is name of my main form.

Comment: Key presses go to the control with the focus.  That will of course not be your form.  Override ProcessCmdKey() to get a sniff at the key first before the control with the focus gets it.  Return *true* when you used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this resource on MSDN for Global Hooks if that is what you intend to do:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx
the Hooks that interest you are WH_KEYBOARD or WH_KEYBOARD_LL according to what you need to do.
I'd suggest you to post your code though so we can check if there is something wrong with your event binding.

Following an example from MSDN by Stephen Toub:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: You should include an example incase the link ever goes dead!

Comment: Gteat thing. WinAPI is always on the help.

Comment: Attribution is important, this is [Stephen Toub's code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).  It is not reliable on .NET 4.0 and up, it no longer fakes module handles for managed assemblies so GetModuleHandle() returns zero.  Be sure to point that out as well that it hooks *all* processes and that RegisterHotKey() is often the better way to do that.